# Google InApp Reviews for Unity: ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Very silly one. I'm trying to integrate Google's In-app Reviews feature into my Unity application and after deploying build I'm getting the following runtime error message on logcat console.

I followed guide from Google and it looks like there are DLLs or scripts missing or I'm doing something terribly wrong. After executing code:

```
private ReviewManager _reviewManager;
void Start{
        _reviewManager = new ReviewManager();
}
```

I receive:

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory
```

Unity 2019.2.21f. Tried Resolving for Android, tried reinstalling Google Play Core, Common and InApp Reviews (1.2.0) components.
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Proguard? You can check it in Player Settings -> Publishing Settings -> Minify. If yes, proguard can remove this part of code. Locate proguard file (Assets/Plugins/Android/proguard-user.txt) and add this line `-keep class com.google.android.play.core.review.** { *;}`

Comment: Do you know why you have to do this ? in unity each plugins has it's own pro guard file with a set of rules